# Cocoapods- Pods install command

Tags: ios, cocoapods

Does 'pods install' command uses the podspec or it only uses the podfile. When I check ./Pods folder, i do not see the source files specified in podspec. What should be done for this. I only see the dependencies specified in the ./Pods folder.

Answer (score 0):

It uses the padfile. First you have to write the pad file.You have to list the dependencies in a text file named Podfile in your Xcode project directory.(use pod init)

eg:

```
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'JSONKit',       '~> 1.4'
pod 'Reachability',  '~> 3.0'
```

Then you can use the pod install command by using the padfile

Comment: It installs the dependencies in my case. But will it not pull the source files that i specified in podspec to the ./Pods folder

Comment: What is the output you are getting, once you execute the command?

Comment: It is giving integrating client project at the end. But, i want to know what will this command do. Does it pull the sources specified in the podspec.

Comment: It is just install the dependencies specified in the podfile.

Comment: but then what is the use of podspec. I want to create a build with the source code and dependencies in the Pod file.

Comment: It allows you to declaratively define project dependencies and have them included in the build of your project. It's like Apache Maven or Ruby Gems for XCode. It supports you to get the dependencies and build your project.

Comment: Follow this article.This will helpful you to understand how to use the cocoapods. http://www.objc.io/issue-6/cocoapods-under-the-hood.html

Comment: I have read that already. Still have queries.Can you explain if you know completely.

Comment: That guidelines of that article works. Seems you having problem with your project layout.Please share the project layout you are using with the podfile.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56255/discussion-between-swgkg-and-user694688).